# Javascript ajax Get call is not accessing Controller method

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, controller

I know there's a lot of questions for this topic, but I can't seem to get it to work even after trying them out. I'm trying to call a controller method that takes in a parameter and returns a string with that parameter, but it's not working. Also, I am executing an ajax GET call to do this.

My controller method:

```
public class TestController: Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public string GetString(string word)
        {
            return "Hello from Get" + word;
        }
    }
```

My javascript code

```
testFunc();

    function testFunc() {
        var word = "yay";
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "Test/GetString", 
            data: word,
            success: function (result) {
                console.log("sucess: " + result);

            },
            error: function (result) {
                console.log("failed.");
            }

        });
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using the `data` property instead of adding word to your url?

Comment: are you able to hit the controller directly from the browser by navigating to `/test/getstring`?  If so, you should be able to look in the network tab and watch your ajax call and try to find anything that doesnt look right.  And like @DavidL said, you probably want to put `word` as a query parameter or route parameter

Comment: @DavidL, managed to figure it out and use your advice to add it into the url. Gonna add the solution later. Thanks

Comment: @Jonesopolis yeah it wasn't getting the method. Did something dumb and forgot to add an asax file which enabled access. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to do something really basic..

I had to add the Global asax file with the following code

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }

    }
```

Then in my controller, I just changed the inherited class from Controller to ApiController which requires the namespace System.Web.Http

```
public class TestController: ApiController
    {
        public string GetString(string word)
        {
            return "Hello from Get: " + word;
        }
    }
```

Finally, in my javascript I used a different get function which worked

```
testFunc();

    function testFunc() {
        var myword = "test";
        $.getJSON('api/test?&word='+myword,
            function (data) {

                console.log(data);

            });
    }
```